# "Can't find variable: setIOSParameters" with FileStack and iOS

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, filestack

Our site uses FileStack and we get frequent frontend (JavaScript) errors reported via Sentry on Mobile Safari (lately iOS 16.2, but it's happened with all version).

```
Can't find variable: setIOSParameters
```

I cannot reproduce this with either the iOS Simulator or a physical device.

Are we doing something wrong, or is there a known fix?

Answer (score 2):

We get those as well, which from a reverse look-up from the IPs showed us an AWS instance, which means it's probably coming from web crawlers. We have started to ignore them using the `ignoreErrors` option when setting up the Sentry SDK.

Our current list:

```
/apstagLOADED is not defined/i,
/__cmp is not defined/i,
/Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cmp')/i,
/Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'outputCurrentConfiguration')/i,
/IMUID is not defined/i,
/jwDefaults is not defined/i,
/YT is not defined/i,
/dailymotion is not defined/i,
/moat_px is not defined/i,
/Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'variables')/i,
/Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ns')/i,
/Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mvpConfig')/i,
/ezDenty is not defined/i,
/Can't find variable: setIOSParameters/i
```